# Git branch and remote in my terminal is different from what I see in github

Tags: git, repository, branch, git-remote

I am learning git and it is getting confusing for me. I am confused about branches, remote repository and directories. Someone else cloned a code on my local machine. When I do `git branch` I see these three branches:

```
ChrisMerge
* EliasWork
develop
```

and when I do `git remote` I get these

```
chris
origin
prime
```

I thought maybe they are directories but I cannot find any directory named chris, develop. So where are the codes stored? Because the codes in each of them are different.

On my git account on github.com, I thought maybe I can see one of these names there. But under branches there are other names like, `devel, ver, ...`
I need someone to make this clear for me once and for all.

Answer (score 2):

A Git *remote* is just a short name under which Git stores some data.  It's not a directory.  Running `git remote` lists all the remote names that Git knows about, which is basically everything that `git config --list` will list that starts with `remote.`: you will see:

```
remote.chris.url = <some url>
remote.origin.url = <another url>
remote.prime.url = <yet another url>
```

and probably additional lines such as:

```
remote.chris.fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/chris/*
```

and so on.  It's these lines' *existence* that creates the so-called remote.  The `fetch` lines in particular tell `git fetch` what your Git should copy from some other Git, and the `url` lines tell your Git how to *contact* each of the other Gits.

---

A *branch name*, by contrast, is a name that *your* Git uses to store one specific commit hash ID.  This name is up to you—it's not controlled by any other Git, it's controlled by you when you ask your Git to create branch names.  In general, if your remote named `origin` has a branch named `master`, *your* Git will remember that name as `origin/master` and you might want your branch name `master` to remember `origin/master` which is your Git's way of remembering the `master` on the Git that your Git calls up via `remote.origin.url`.

Git calls these names—`origin/master` and so on—*remote-tracking names* or *remote-tracking branch names*.  They are not actually branch names, and they are different from (but obviously related to) the *remotes*.  They're used for your Git to remember ("track") the branches *on* the remote, which is why they are called *remote-tracking names*.

---

Normally, none of this is particularly confusing, because most users in their Git repositories have only *one* remote, named `origin`, so their `master` will go along with `origin/master`.  But in your case, you have *three* remotes.  The Git at the URL named via `prime` probably *also* has a `master`, which your Git will remember via `prime/master`.  So now you have both `origin/master` and `prime/master`.  If you want to work with these, the usual recommendation would be to use your branch named `master` to work with `origin/master`, and to use your branch named `master` to work with `prime/master`.  But this is doomed to failure—so you'll need to use some *other* local branch name(s), and that's where things get confusing.

Fortunately, as we just saw, your own branch names *don't* have to match some remote's name.  You can have a branch like `EliasWork` that is, or is not, connected to *any* of your remote-tracking names.  The limitation is that each branch name can only have *one* of these set.  Git calls this the *upstream* of the branch.

---

Extra-confusingly, when we set a remote-tracking name as the upstream of a branch, Git says that this branch is now "tracking" that remote-tracking name.  So now we have:

- A *branch name*, which is a local name we make up for ourselves ...
- that is *tracking* (as a stand-alone word) an *upstream* made out of ...
- a *remote-tracking name* or *remote-tracking branch-name*, which, as a complete phrase, is really a local name ...
- that remembers a *branch name* as seen on a *remote* ...
- where a *remote* is a short name for a URL for some other Git repository (whew!).

Note that this keeps re-using various words, and having them mean different things!  As terminology goes, it leaves a lot to be desired.

In any case, none of these are directories that you will see in your *work-tree*, which is where you do your work.  (Git will sometimes create some directories within `.git` using these names, but the `.git` directory, which stores the repository itself, is not technically included in your work-tree.)

Answer (score 0):

Because I did not know even very basic things I could not ask the right questions. I tried to read and read and to understand git a little bit. I want to share the basic things that I did not know and hopefully it helps people who are not majored in computer science like me to understand git. Note that I am not trying to be accurate here, I just want you to get started like I did. You can see this awesome [tutorial](https://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/git/) for more information.

1. This is commit objects that has all the files
2. The difference between commit objects are usually modified or added files. So they can have different files
3. Branches are commit objects that we name them. Their purpose is to add some features or fix some bugs. In my case, ChrisMerge,EliasWork and develop.
4. Otherwise, every commit object has a long name called SHA1. For example,
   my EliasWork branch has this SHA1:
   007415674d8e44908ce2786e164e9e8a751c3984 
   and a98fd670b9b5c39c8b049671a349f9dfd7b362e3 is a commit object that has no particular branch or head name but the other commit object that I mentioned has a name, EliasWork.
5. practically head means the general branch name, and HEAD is the branch that is active.
6. by active branch, I mean when you look at that directory you see the files related to that branch. if you change your active branch you see different files.
7. So it is like you have some branches that act like different directories. but you can only see and modify the files for the active branch. EliasWork is active branch here and I see those files related to this branch.
8. Chris, origin and prime are remote repositories. They have their own branches and commits. here origin is the one that I see on my github account. I have cloned this remote repository on my local machine and I have all its commit objects but I only have the remote active branch, i.e. develop, and not its other branches. And then I created another branch called EliasWork so I can modify the codes and later on push it to main repository